# Entering a Float Value into a TextField

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I Want to enter amount in a textField i kept a place holder 0.00
If i enter a value the value should come to the left side of the decimal point and the 00 should stay still.
How?

Comment: try

[txtField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.00", yourFloatValue]];

Comment: the value is getting added after the 0's in this case

Comment: This would give something like 12.34.00 :-) - it should be %d.00

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the following methods

– textViewShouldBeginEditing:

– textViewDidBeginEditing:

– textViewShouldEndEditing:

– textViewDidEndEditing:

for appending 00 after the entered number.

Answer (score 0):

I take it the .00 always stays .00, so you cannot change the value after the decimal point?

Then you should implement the text field delegate

`-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string`

This is called any time a user enters a character, so you can easily use it to change the displayed text in the textfield to show the entered number formatted with

`textField.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.00", intNumberEnteredUpToNow];`

Of course you should test the entered character (it could be a backspace or a letter, depending on the keyboard you are showing), and put the parts before the decimal point that are currently shown into the **intNumberEnteredUpToNow** value.

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention it. even that 00 should change